# ARKit: pausing session does not stop the scene to be called

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skscene, arkit

I'm using `ARKit` with `SpriteKit`. My AR feature is not a core feature in my app, users may optionally navigate to a viewController with an `ARSKView` where I configure and set an `SKScene` in the `ARsession`.

I pause the session when the user navigates back:

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)   
    sceneView.session.pause()
}
```

then the viewController is pop from the navigationController where it was pushed. But I'm seeing that the func `update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval)` in my `SKScene` subclass keeps being called... which is the appropriate way to also stop that? I thought that pausing the `ARSession` would also stop the scene.

**EDIT:** when I navigate back from the view controller that holds the `ARSKView` and it is deinitialized, I see that the `SKScene` is still in memory and a new one is created every time I navigate again to the AR related view controller. So, if I navigate there N times, I see I have N `SKScene`s in memory. How could I appropiately remove the scene when navigating back? The `scene` property of the `ARsession` is read only.

Comment: pause the view, `sceneView.isPaused = true`, or pause the scene, `sceneView.scene.isPaused = true` depending on what you need

Comment: @Knight0fDragon thank you. However, since my app is not focused in `ARKit` but an additional feature, user can navigate back from the view controller that holds the `ARSKView`. I've noticed that pausing the `SKScene` is not enough, it still lives after the view controller is deinit, how should I "destroy" the scene?

Comment: @AppsDev did you find a solution?

Comment: @Knight0fDragon there doesn't appear to be `isPaused` for SCNView, only `pause()`

Comment: @Crashalot this is about SKView

Comment: @Knight0fDragon correct you are! apologies. :)

Comment: @AppsDev did you find any solution?

Comment: I mean who would ever want to properly stop an ARSession, once started hey. Nobody surely ;) -Yeah, this is a fairly major oversight on Apple's part. @AppsDev Did you figure this out?

Answer (score 3):

that sounds like a memory retain issue. Make sure that any node in you SKScene subclass is properly removed and deinitialized.
Set your scene delegate to nil, set any node or array of nodes referenced in your VC to nil.

I ran a simple test with 2 VC embedded in a navigation controller, the first one has a view with a start button, the second one is the ARVC. 
I run the session, set my custom scene delegate to ARVC, when I hit the back button everything stops by itself and my ARVC is being popped. Nothing in memory.

So make sure that you manually remove all your nodes and their animations, constraints, actions and anything that relates to you custom SKScene subclass.
Also don't be afraid to call sceneView.presentScene(nil) if that can help.

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't find any official documentation about this, apparently there is not proper method to stop a session yet. What I found that was similar to your scenario is this [work around](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52769317/swift-arkit-how-do-you-fully-kill-an-arsession).

It suggests you create `ARSKView` as disposable and before leaving your controller, pause the session, remove the view from superview and assign it to nil.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.