# Swift ARKit How do you fully kill an ARSession?

Tags: swift, arkit, arscnview

I have an `ARSCNView` running an `ARSession`. You can pause the session with `session.pause()` sure, but that still in effect, leaves the session running. I have tried deallocating the `ARSCNView` by removing it from its superview. The `ARSCNView` indeed deallocates but the `ARSession` is still running afterwards!! You can't assign `nil` to `ARSession` either. I can see the `ARSessionDelegate`'s

```
func session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate frame: ARFrame)
```

is still being called!

How do you completely wipe the slate clean with ARKit once you have finished with it?

Is it even possible?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve on didUpdate?

Comment: Nothing, it’s just a way of seeing that the session is still running.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: Apple don’t provide a way to sensibly end the ARSession at present. But I did find a work-around which works.

Comment: @GeoffH I have the same question, do you mind sharing the workaround that works for you? For me, I am trying alternate between arsession and an avcapture session. I see strange behavior and suspect it’s related to the presence of arsession

Comment: @kawingkelvin In short, you make the ARSCNView hierarchy disposable. The other non-AR areas of your app would be in separate view hierarchies at a sibling level to your ARSCNView. When you need AR mode, you build the ARSCNView hierarchy (and subsequently start an ARSession). When you’re done, you deallocate the entire ARSCNView hierarchy and switch to the other view hierarchy in your app. Rebuild again when going back to AR. I wish there was a more intuitive way provided by Apple. But at the time of writing, there isn’t. This is the next best thing though.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Officially, right now, you can't.**

However, there is a work-around: you make the `ARSCNView` disposable.

On leaving AR, first pause the `ARSession`. Then deallocate the entire `ARSCNView` hierarchy & set `ARSCNView` to `nil` for good measure. Rebuild the entire `ARSCNView` hierarchy and start a new session whenever you need to go back to AR.

```
var ARview: ARSCNView?

func punchTheClown() {

    ARView?.session.pause()
    ARView?.removeFromSuperview()
    ARView = nil

}
```

Other non-AR areas of your app would typically be in a separate view hierarchy at the same sibling level as your `ARSCNView`. I look forward to Apple providing an actual `stopSession()` function, so we can all stop having to punchTheClown in the meantime.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I could see the session being active even after I set the scene view object to nil. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Same problem on RealityKit´s ARView(). It doesn't work for me either, not found a way to deallocate it from memory at all.

Comment: Doesn't work.  Even did arView.window?.resignKey(), arView.scene.anchors.removeAll(), arView.session.delegate = nil.  Somehow it still stays around, and when creating a new ARView, you get the yellow "Tap to Resume"

Comment: Now This solved my issue

Answer (score 2):

*From the docs*

> While paused, the session doesn't track device motion or capture scene
>   imagery, nor does it coordinate with its delegate object or update any
>   associated ARSCNView or ARSKView object

If it isn’t causing issues, better be left alone. As far as I know. This works like a video player. You can ***Pause*** and *resume* it anytime

Source here: [.RunOptions ARKit Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arsession/runoptions)

Comment: Good to know. Sometimes, you can't afford to just leave it alone though. I need to free-up the resources. The app is not solely spent in augmented reality. The SCNSceneRenderer for the ARSCNView is killing all updating of other things & will not stop unless you destroy the ARSCNView. How to we kill the session?

Comment: This no longer works as of iOS 17 — tracking continues totally unaffected by calling .pause()!