# How to deallocate RealityKit ARView()?

Tags: swift, swiftui, arkit, realitykit

I cannot manage to release my RealityKit `ARView()` from memory.

I am aware that there are (were?) similar issues with ARKit + SceneKit – with workarounds like this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53919730/7826293
which doesen´t solve my problem unfortunately.

The solutions above kind of work by removing everything "suspicious" manually. That is exactly what I did in a even wider scope:

```
class ViewController_ARViewMemoryTest: UIViewController {

    var arView: ARView?

    init() {
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
        arView = ARView(frame: .zero)
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    deinit {
        doEverythingThatsNeeded()
    }

    public func doEverythingThatsNeeded() {
        self.arView?.session.pause()
        self.arView?.session.delegate = nil
        self.arView?.removeFromSuperview()
        // Quite a few more removals and resets here, ie. for Combines AnyCancellables
        self.arView = nil
    }

}
```

I am calling doEverythingThatsNeeded() from outside as well:

```
aRViewMemoryTest?.doEverythingThatsNeeded()
aRViewMemoryTest?.arView = nil
aRViewMemoryTest = nil
```

The issue seems to be independent from the fact that I have wrapped my ARView or alternatively a UIViewController in a SwiftUI `UIViewRepresentable` / `UIViewControllerRepresentable`.

I believe it must be a bug and I have filed a report months ago. However I am hoping for workarounds that help until Apple fixes the potential issue.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: do you find anything?

Comment: 2+ years later the problem seems to persist.

Answer (score 2):

**RealityKit v2.0 | March 30, 2023**.

#### UIKit version

Here's how you can start the deallocation process in UIKit:

```
import UIKit
import RealityKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var arView: ARView? = ARView(frame: .zero)

    deinit { removingView() }
    
    func addingView() {
        self.arView?.frame = .init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 700)
        self.view.addSubview(arView!)
    }
    
    func removingView() {
        self.arView?.session.pause()            // there's no session on macOS
        self.arView?.session.delegate = nil     // there's no session on macOS
        self.arView?.scene.anchors.removeAll()
        self.arView?.removeFromSuperview()
        self.arView?.window?.resignKey()
        self.arView = nil
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()            
        addingView()
        
        let boxAnchor = try! Experience.loadBox()
        arView?.scene.anchors.append(boxAnchor)
        
        removingView()
    }
}
```

The real problem, however, is that when ARView is deinitialized, the memory allocated for it is not fully deallocated (even though the code is 100% correct). Nevertheless, there's good news too - when you use this ARView again, the same allocated memory will be used.

If you need more info, please read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71678361/why-does-realitykit-memory-does-not-clear-after-deinit-called/71844537#71844537) for details.

#### SwiftUI version

Since SwiftUI views are values, no deallocation process is needed for them, like in UIKit (I mean `deinit` methods). However, if we remove ARView from superview, the memory leak will still occur.

[image]

```
import SwiftUI
import RealityKit

struct ContentView : View {
        
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            ZStack {
                Color.black
                                
                VStack {
                    NavigationLink(destination: RealityKitView()) {
                        Text("Load AR Scene")
                            .foregroundColor(.mint)
                            .font(.title2)
                    }
                }
            }.ignoresSafeArea()
        }
    }
}
```

Here is ARViewContainer's `init(isTapped: Binding<Bool>)`.

```
struct RealityKitView : View {
    
    @State private var isTapped: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.orange.ignoresSafeArea()
            Text("ARView was removed")
                .font(.title3)
            
            ARViewContainer(isTapped: $isTapped)
                .ignoresSafeArea()
            VStack {
                Spacer()
                Button("Remove ARView") {
                    isTapped = true
                }
                .disabled(isTapped ? true : false)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And let's implement the method that unlinks the view from its superview.

```
struct ARViewContainer : UIViewRepresentable {
    
    let arView = ARView(frame: .zero)
    @Binding var isTapped: Bool
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> ARView {
        let model = ModelEntity(mesh: .generateSphere(radius: 0.25))
        let anchor = AnchorEntity()
        model.setParent(anchor)
        arView.scene.anchors.append(anchor)
        return arView
    }
    func updateUIView(_ view: ARView, context: Context) {
        if isTapped {
            view.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }
}
```

P. S.

Alas, Apple engineers have not yet solved the ARView's memory leak problem...

Comment: Thanks! I am not using an Experience. But otherwise I have stripped down my code to only the AppDelegate and your class, plus a button which sets the viewController to nil: Still no success.

Comment: Hey @AndyFedo, thanks again. Could you comment on which role the `updateUIView(_ uiView: ARView, context:  UIViewRepresentableContext<ARViewContainer>)` method plays in this context? If I start an empty ARView in `makeUIView(context: Context) -> ARView` containing `ARView(frame: somethingNotZero)` I see the memory overhead of about 400MB for the started session. So far so good. No success in getting rid of the memory consumption either...

Comment: Hi @Andy, did you any success on this?

Comment: Hi @HelloTimo. Not yet.

Comment: I am not quite sure if I am dealing with a framework bug or simply do something wrong. Any input appreciated.

Comment: @AndyJazz the SwiftUI version works, but there should be a note that `updateUIView` can be called before `ARViewContainer` needs to be unloaded. Thanks for this answer though as it definitely helped deallocate the container.

Comment: what's the point of doing `uiView.removeFromSuperview()` in the `updateUIView`? it will simply not work since it will remove the ARView after it will create it from the `makeUIView`

Comment: I just demonstrated how easy it is to delete a view in SwiftUI (added `asyncAfter`).

Comment: I have this same problem in SwiftUI.  I have a button that dismisses the ARView and it also does removeFromSuperview() in updateUIView.  And I used your asyncAfter with  + 3.0 but the memory is still not being deallocated.  Plus, if I come back to opening the ARView again, I get a crash since it was removed from the superview.  So the deallocation of memory works for you in SwiftUI?