# RealityKit – Can't deallocate ARView

Tags: swift, arkit, realitykit

I'm using a `ARView` to show AR content in my app, but on dismissing the view controller, the memory is not completely deallocated.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59909045/how-to-deallocate-realitykit-arview) question, but I had no luck with the answer.

The memory consumption looks like this:

[image: memory consumption graph]

The entire codebase is very simple:

I've got a button that on pressing it, executes this:

```
    let vc = SecondViewController()
    self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: {
        print("done")
    })
```

and `SecondViewController` is a simple as this:

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var arView: ARView?
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.arView = ARView(frame: self.view.frame)
        self.view.addSubview(arView!)
        arView!.automaticallyConfigureSession = true
        
    }
    
    deinit {
        self.arView?.session.pause()
        self.arView?.session.delegate = nil
        self.arView?.scene.anchors.removeAll()
        self.arView?.removeFromSuperview()
        self.arView?.window?.resignKey()
        self.arView = nil
        
    }
}
```

But on dismissing, as can be seen in the memory graph, the memory is not deallocated fully.

Comment: Hi @Will, here's my answer on this topic – https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71678361/why-does-realitykit-memory-does-not-clear-after-deinit-called/71844537#71844537